# Filtro com consulta SQL à partir de um combobox - c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Estou criando um programa de estoque e gostaria que a consulta de itens fosse filtrada por um combobox, ou seja, que ao escrever no campo de buscas só apareçam os resultados referentes ao parâmetro do combobox.

Este é o meu código de consulta SQL:

```
DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select " +
                                       "sc.scat_cod, sc.scat_nome, sc.cat_cod, c.cat_nome " +
                                       "from subcategoria sc " +
                                       "inner join categoria c on sc.cat_cod = c.cat_cod " +
                                       "where " +
                                       "(sc.scat_nome like '%" + valor + "%') or (c.cat_nome like '%" + valor + "%')", conexao.StringConexao);

da.Fill(tabela);
return tabela;
```

Com este código ao digitar no campo de pesquisa o parâmetro some e são mostrados todos os resultados, sem filtro nenhum, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema que me aflige?

Comment: você precisa qualificar o filtro e trabalhar com suas condições... apresente o resto do método, se não não tem como ajudar

Comment: Poste detalhes do contexto, pois o enunciado está muito vago. Por exemplo: no combobox podem ser marcadas várias subcategorias de uma única categoria OU vários pares categoria+subcategoria?

Answer (score 0):

Só fazer uma verificação se o valor está preenchido e caso esteja nulo ou vazio retornas a DataTable sem nada.

```
DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor)) return tabela;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select " +
                                       "sc.scat_cod, sc.scat_nome, sc.cat_cod, c.cat_nome " +
                                       "from subcategoria sc " +
                                       "inner join categoria c on sc.cat_cod = c.cat_cod " +
                                       "where " +
                                       "(sc.scat_nome like '%" + valor + "%') or (c.cat_nome like '%" + valor + "%')", conexao.StringConexao);

da.Fill(tabela);
return tabela;
```